# chart.js pie chart create original legend in a seperate div (working) now can't hide bar chart element(s) onclick

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js

The Doughnut and Pie chart in chartjs (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) has a legend, which can be enabled via

```
this.setOptions({
  legend: {
    display: true,
}
```

Sadly, the legend is in the same canvas as the chart itself. I'd simply like to have it outside of it in a different div.

I've tried to simply create a new Legend via `legendCallback`:

```
legendCallback: function(chart) {
    var text = [];
    text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
    for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
          text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '">');
      if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
        text.push(chart.data.labels[i]);
      }
      text.push('</span></li>');
      }
text.push('</ul>');
return text.join("");
},
```

and then adding it with (for example) a

```
    animation: {
    onComplete: function(chart){
    document.getElementById('legendDiv').innerHTML=this.chart.generateLegend();
  }
```

Obviously I've also also put a div with the id `legenDiv` somewhere as well.
Nearly all of this does work. Sadly, the CSS got overwritten from the standard one, looking something like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spkzJ.png)
  so now I thought that `<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">` would more or less take the default `ul` layout, but it doesn't. Also the onclick hide feature doesn't work anymore. There is also the chart.js documentation for the doughnut controller, which I tried to overtake, but couldn't get to work... (github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/controllers/controller.doughnut.js#L42-L69)

Can someone please just help me find a very easy solution to just move the original legend from the canvas to a div elsewhere. If that doesn't work, please help me doing a pretty much look-alike new legend.

Update:

```
getChartLegend(){
if( this.chartJsObject == null )
  return null;
var list = $( '<ul class="list-unstyled"></ul>' );
for (var i=0; i<this.chartJsObject.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
  var item = $( "<li></li>" );
  var span = $( '<span class="color-box" style="background-color: ' + this.chartJsObject.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '"></span>' );
  span.appendTo( item );
  var label = $( "<label class='chart-label'>" + this.chartJsObject.data.labels[i] + " </label>" );
  label.appendTo( item );
  var clickFunction = function( event )
  {
    var meta = event.data.chart.getDatasetMeta( 0 );
    console.log(event.data.chart.getDatasetMeta( 0 ));
    if (meta.data[event.data.index]) {
      meta.data[event.data.index].hidden = !meta.data[event.data.index].hidden;
    }
    if( !event.data.item.hasClass( "text-cross" ) )
      event.data.item.addClass( "text-cross" );
    else
      event.data.item.removeClass( "text-cross" );
    event.data.chart.update();
  };
  label.click( { index: i, item: label, chart: this.chartJsObject }, clickFunction );
  span.click( { index: i, item: label, chart: this.chartJsObject }, clickFunction );
  item.appendTo( list );
}
return list;
}
```

I'm now using this code with my own CSS and everything works just fine. But only with my Doughnut-Chats. My bar-chart doesn't seem to respond to

```
if (meta.data[event.data.index]) {
      meta.data[event.data.index].hidden = !meta.data[event.data.index].hidden;
    }
```

Although the element's hidden property get's changed to hidden just fine. It just doesn't seem to work with bar chart object elements.  Anyone got a work-around?